# Use id column of parent query in subquery mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

i've this query (works) :

```
SELECT NOME, AMPM, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(PERITI,' (',QTY,')') SEPARATOR ', ')periti FROM 
(SELECT zone.nome, DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(appuntamenti.data_inizio,' ',appuntamenti.ora_inizio), '%p') AMPM, 
periti.sigla PERITI,COUNT(*) QTY FROM appuntamenti 
inner join periti on appuntamenti.id_perito = periti.id 
inner join zone on appuntamenti.id_zona = zone.id 
where appuntamenti.data_inizio='2018-11-20' and appuntamenti.id_zona = '77'
GROUP BY AMPM, PERITI) AS GIORNO1AM
union
SELECT NOME, AMPM, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(PERITI,' (',QTY,')') SEPARATOR ', ')periti FROM 
(SELECT zone.nome, DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(appuntamenti.data_inizio,' ',appuntamenti.ora_inizio), '%p') AMPM, 
periti.sigla PERITI,COUNT(*) QTY FROM appuntamenti 
inner join periti on appuntamenti.id_perito = periti.id 
inner join zone on appuntamenti.id_zona = zone.id 
where appuntamenti.data_inizio='2018-11-20' and appuntamenti.id_zona = '78'
GROUP BY AMPM, PERITI) AS GIORNO1AM
union
SELECT NOME, AMPM, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(PERITI,' (',QTY,')') SEPARATOR ', ')periti FROM 
(SELECT zone.nome, DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(appuntamenti.data_inizio,' ',appuntamenti.ora_inizio), '%p') AMPM, 
periti.sigla PERITI,COUNT(*) QTY FROM appuntamenti 
inner join periti on appuntamenti.id_perito = periti.id 
inner join zone on appuntamenti.id_zona = zone.id 
where appuntamenti.data_inizio='2018-11-20' and appuntamenti.id_zona = '79'
GROUP BY AMPM, PERITI) AS GIORNO1AM
order by NOME ASC
```

i want to remove all the "union" from the query and use instead **id column** from **zone table** in the nested where clause.

something like :

```
SELECT p.id ,(SELECT NOME, AMPM, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(PERITI,' (',QTY,')') SEPARATOR ', ')periti FROM 
(SELECT zone.nome, DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(appuntamenti.data_inizio,' ',appuntamenti.ora_inizio), '%p') AMPM, 
periti.sigla PERITI,COUNT(*) QTY FROM appuntamenti 
inner join periti on appuntamenti.id_perito = periti.id 
inner join zone on appuntamenti.id_zona = zone.id 
where appuntamenti.data_inizio='2018-11-20' and appuntamenti.id_zona = p.id
GROUP BY AMPM, PERITI) AS GIORNO1AM) AS RISULTATO
FROM zone p
```

but... when i try this change, i got this error :

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause'

please help me :)

Comment: You can't reference outer-level columns deeper than one level and you trying to call outer id from level 2. You'll need to rewrite the query

Comment: could you please tell me the correct way to do this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Am I seeing correctly that all the elements of union are the same apart from appuntamenti.id_zona? If so wouldn't that just work:

```
SELECT NOME, AMPM, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(PERITI,' (',QTY,')') SEPARATOR ', ')periti FROM 
(SELECT zone.nome, DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(appuntamenti.data_inizio,' ',appuntamenti.ora_inizio), '%p') AMPM, 
periti.sigla PERITI,COUNT(*) QTY FROM appuntamenti 
inner join periti on appuntamenti.id_perito = periti.id 
inner join zone on appuntamenti.id_zona = zone.id 
where appuntamenti.data_inizio='2018-11-20' and appuntamenti.id_zona IN (77, 78,79)
GROUP BY AMPM, PERITI) AS GIORNO1AM
```

Comment: it's correct, but the result is a one row only, i need a single row for every appuntamenti.id_zona.. how i can get this? thanks in advance

Comment: It's a bit hard without having the layout of input data. Try to remove AMPM from GROUP BY and see if that points you in the right direction. I could help if you'd set up a  http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some example data and my query

Answer (score 0):

In general, to check if a subquery works, it should be runnable on their own.

So in your case, this query should be successful:

```
(SELECT zone.nome,
        Date_format(Concat(appuntamenti.data_inizio, ' ', 
                    appuntamenti.ora_inizio), '%p' 
        ) AMPM, 
        periti.sigla PERITI, 
        Count(*) QTY 
  FROM  appuntamenti 
  INNER JOIN periti 
        ON appuntamenti.id_perito = periti.id 
  INNER JOIN zone 
        ON appuntamenti.id_zona = zone.id 
  WHERE  appuntamenti.data_inizio = '2018-11-20' 
         AND appuntamenti.id_zona = p.id 
  GROUP  BY ampm, 
            periti)
```

From the query above, there is no table named `p`.

I'm not sure what results you want to achieve, an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would help :)

But assuming you want to connect the subquery to the outer table, you would be needing an **INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT p.id,
       subquery.nome
       group_concat(concat(periti, ' (', subquery.qty, ')') SEPARATOR ', ') periti
FROM   zone p 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT zone.nome,
                   Date_format(Concat(appuntamenti.data_inizio,
                               ' ', vappuntamenti.ora_inizio), '%p'
                               ) AMPM, 
                   periti.sigla PERITI, 
                   Count(*)     QTY
                   appuntamenti.id_zona /* <- reference from outer table */         
            FROM   appuntamenti 
            INNER JOIN periti 
                  ON appuntamenti.id_perito = periti.id 
            INNER JOIN zone 
                  ON appuntamenti.id_zona = zone.id 
            WHERE  appuntamenti.data_inizio = '2018-11-20' 
            GROUP  BY ampm,  periti) AS subquery ON subquery.id_zona = p.id
```